# UIImagePickerController crash on presentmodal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

Hello everyone i am having a crash when trying to present camera modally. here is my code :

> if (!imagePicker) {
>           imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
>       }

```
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];


[imagePicker setDelegate:self];

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

[imagePicker release];
```

I have been through all searches here, but commonly **the crash happens only after you taken a picture in**

> imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

i am not getting any details just the app closes and i see the thread is paused.

Any idea what's wrong here. For info i am testing in ipod touch 3G and iPhone 3GS and it

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Comment: In my debug navigator i see nothing except Thread paused and yeah i got memory warning 2 times :)

Comment: enable your zombie objects to have better crash log.

Comment: If the application is really crashing you might find some logs at ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ or ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>. The behavior you describe could simply be the application switching out which is why the thread pauses instead of crashes.

Comment: Make sure you set `imagePicker` to `nil` in the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` method. Failing to do so is the likely cause of your problem.

Comment: @vishwa.deepak thanks for the tip :) . but it didn't helped i just got memory warning in console

Comment: @aqua yes the application is switching out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImagePickerController` can be a pain.  Try

```
imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init] autorelease];
```

and remove the `[imagePicker release]`;

Frankly I wouldn't trust that conditional assignment by simply testing `if(!imagePicker)`.

Comment: ok tks @Richard i have edited the code and now it looks like this :                imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init] autorelease];
    
    
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    
    
 [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    
 [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
 but still crashing ..

Answer (score 0):

clear the imagePicker variable after you release it or it will still be non-null when you go to take the second picture and crash because its actually been released.

```
[imagePicker release];
imagePicker = nil;
```

Answer (score -1):

`-(void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

and

`- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

are Deprecated in iOS 6.0 so instead these method use respectively

`- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`

and

`- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`

Comment: This is irrelevant to the problem. But notice that the question states that testing is on an iPhone 3G. The 3G only supports up to iOS 4.2.1.

Comment: but rmaddy he has to know about this. because the ending of this is to submit it to app store.